# $A$ is compact operator

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $A : l_p \to l_p, 1 \le p \le \infty$ be an operator defined by $A\left ( x_n \right ) = \left ( a_n x_n \right )$ where $\left \{ a_n \right \}$ is a bounded real sequence. Prove that $A$ is compact if and only if $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n =0$.

---

$A$-compact if and only if $A(B)$ is relatively compact, where $B$ is the unit sphere in $l_p$. I don't know how to use this hypothesis. Is there another standard to verify the compactness of an operator?

Comment: Note that finite rank operators (meaning that the dimension of the image is finite) are compact and that the compact operators are norm-closed. So if you can show that an operator is a (norm-) limit of finite rank operators, you know it's compact...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint for $\implies$:** $(e_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ (the standard basis) is a bounded sequence in $\ell^2$, as is any subsequence of $(e_n)$.  The image of any such sequence must have a convergent subsequence.

**Hint for $\Longleftarrow$:** If $a_n \to 0$, show that $A(B)$ is compact.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,  it is equivalent to show that an operator is compact if it sends all bounded sequences into sequences that have a convergent subsequence.   That's often an easier criteria to work with.